# Google maps API v3 how do you recompose ThoroughfareName?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm using the ThoroughfareName property of google maps api v2 which is very handy to get only the address part.

I didn't see any equivalent to this in api v3. Is there some best practices / recognized algorithm to build it back using address_components ?

Comment: I have the same problem please help us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far what I have done is use the route type of address_components + the street_number. This is probably not the correct algorithm but it suits my needs.

Comment: Not for international addresses like in Germany, as here we have the number after the street name.

Comment: Yes the number after the street name it's what I do here : address_components (route essentially) + street_number so after the street name as in Germany and in many other countries ;-)

Comment: In my migration I've used something like this (which is most probably incomplete and not perfect): `$marker['street'] = in_array($new_marker['countrycode'], array('DE', 'AT', 'CH', 'BE', 'NL')? trim($new_marker['street_name'].' '.$new_marker['street_number']) : trim($new_marker['street_number'].' '.$new_marker['street_name']);`

Comment: It's better you are right too take other country specificity. I did not because I only use the service in CH.